# 'Team Forestress 2' won't delete?

Tags: macos

It takes up a lot of storage(20 GB), and I can't locate it in finder either. I can only see it in storage settings, where it won't delete. I also don't have steam anymore.

Answer (score 1):

macOS apps like *Steam* try to keep files you're not supposed to interact with directly (like the resource files needed to run *Team Fortress 2*) tucked away in the normally-invisible "Library" folder. You can either reinstall *Steam*, and tell it to uninstall *TF2*, or you can manually remove the files it left behind. To manually remove it:

1. Start in the app, *Finder*
2. Open the Go menu
3. Hold option—you'll see a new item appear; Library
4. Click Library to open it (then release
   option)
5. Open Application Support
6. Drag the Steam folder to the trash

Note that there may be files you care about, like non-cloud-syncing game saves or other Steam apps, in that Steam folder. Almost everything in Steam can just be re-downloaded later, but in doing the above you naturally assume the risk of damaging or losing anything stored there.

Having typed all that, naturally I just found the [Steam Support article](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3329-WUJN-5636) saying the same things.